# Does threaded network sender/receiver make sense for a game server?

Tags: multithreading, network-programming, client-server

The common approach I see online is have the receiver poll a socket, and when a packet is received do some game work then send the response, repeat, all in a single thread. Trying to do this x times a second seems like a bad idea as game can block the network, and the network can block the game.

Here’s what I have in mind:

**GameApp** – runs on the main thread. It takes two wait free command queues, in commands and out commands.

**OutCommandProcessor** - runs on its own thread; consumes the out command queue from the GameApp and converts the commands to packets and sends them over the network; this thread sleeps when out command queue is empty, and waked up by GameApp when commands are placed in the queue

**InCommandProcessor** – runs on its own thread; converts packet to commands and pushes to the in command queue consumed by GameApp; always runs as it is polling the socket.

My reasons of doing this over single thread are:

1. The network does not block the game, say if the network hangs, the game continues to operate.
2. If the GameApp is busy, commands continue to queue up rather than blocking the network from receiving more packets. GameApp also benefits from reduced latency because it doesn’t get blocked by sending packets.
3. Good separation of concerns as I can test game input and output independent of network stack.

Do you think this a good idea? Would a single threaded event based/active object pattern work better? Or something even better? Thanks!

Comment: Both approaches are fine. Choosing which approach is better requires lots of detailed information that we don't have such as: What do you want to do if network traffic builds up? How much work do the in and out command processors do? Can they block on anything other than the network? What libraries or tools do you plan to use and what models do they work best with? And so on.

Comment: The downside of this approach -- to receive a request, process it, and send a reply, you need two or three context switches, and the data needs to be handed from one thread to another several times. However, the rebuttal to that is that's really only true if the system is idle, and that's not really the case you need to optimize for.

Comment: As David indicated, this also depends on the language/framework you want to use. Some networking libraries (for example libevent) use their own thread and in that case I'd say it makes little sense to put more layers in between. Or rather: It already does what you describe (libevent receives and sends in the same thread though).

Comment: I usually keep the serialization process (command to packet conversion) in the main thread. I simply write to a buffer and pass the buffer to the networking library (nonblocking). There might be options to do this without copying.

Comment: Thanks. The only context switch overhead that I can see being problematic is when waking up the sender thread, which if the server/client is running should never sleep. If say no commands are being sent for x amount of time then go to sleep (i.e. all clients disconnected). I can also see how it makes sense to put command to packet conversion on the main thread as long as the conversion process is not too expensive. As send operations are bottlenecked by GameApp anyways, and can save copying operations like 1000ml said.

Comment: The general intention is that packets should be processed in a timely manner. The main concern I had was if the GameApp was waiting for a critical packet, the network would be blocked. But GameApp can still be designed in such a way that it can continue to do work and wait for the packet again on the next frame. New packets can still be processed in the meantime. For use of thread however, if the GameApp work per tick becomes more expensive, it has no affect on the receiving side. This might reduce complexity if say a separate module to handle incoming commands.